# Java: Why doesn't JTable use TableCellEditor?

Tags: java, jtable, tablecelleditor

The intention of MyTableCellEditor is to make a JTable cell behave like an Excel cell, IOW, entering a value after single clicking in a cell overwrites rather than appends to the existing value.
I didn't expect the following code to work on the first pass, but I did expect to be hit debug breakpoints in getTableCellEditorComponent and getCellEditorValue.
Why isn't getTableCellEditorComponent or getCellEditorValue called when I use jTable?

```
public class MyTable extends javax.swing.JFrame implements TableModelListener {
    private static final MyTableCellEditor tableCellEditor =
        new MyTableCellEditor();
        ...
    public MyTable() {
        initComponents();
        jTable.getModel().addTableModelListener(MyTable.this);
        ...
    private void initComponents() { // Generated by the Form Editor.
        jTable = new javax.swing.JTable();
        jTable.setCellEditor(tableCellEditor);
        ...
public class MyTableCellEditor extends AbstractCellEditor implements
        TableCellEditor {
    JComponent component = new JTextField();
    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value,
            boolean isSelected, int rowIndex, int vColIndex) {
        if (isSelected) {
            ((JTextField)component).selectAll();
        }
        ((JTextField)component).setText((String)value);
        return component;
    }
    public Object getCellEditorValue() {
        return ((JTextField)component).getText();
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated, but why don't you just declare `component` as a `JTextField` and avoid yourself a bunch of casting?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`setCellEditor(TableCellEditor)` sets the editor for the currently *active* cell only (and will be lost once it's no longer active.  You want to call `JTable.setDefaultEditor()` to set the default editor for a specific class.

```
jTable.setDefaultEditor(String.class, tableCellEditor);
```

Alternatively, you can set an editor for the column through the `TableColumnModel`, eg

```
jTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setCellEditor(tableCellEditor);
```

Comment: Both lines of code seem to do nothing at all :(
Any possible reason ?